# Included jar files but get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver Error

Tags: jdbc, teradata

I have added the `terajdbc4.jar` and `tdgssconfig.jar` into my `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder but on running the application, i get the following Error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)

my .classpath file in the project application folder also contains reference to the added jars as shown below
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/tdgssconfig.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/terajdbc4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used another version of jars and it solved the issue.
The jars I use now are :

1. teradata-jdbc4-14.00.00.04
2. teradata-config-14.00.00.04

Earlier I used :

1. terajdbc4.jar
2. tdgssjava.jar